# Embedding Videos from Mobile Web App

Tags: video, mobile, mobile-website, web-applications

I have been looking for information on embedding videos on a mobile website. Here are a few questions I have:

1) I know that using an HTML5 `<video>` tag will work with iPhone and Android, but is there a specific way that I should go about doing this for other phones? I know I will struggle with blackberries, but what about HTC phones, or windows phones? Will they be fine here? Most phones say they support HTML5, so is it a safe assumption that videos will be supported?

2) Concerning phones like Blackberries , would it be possible to just implement a regular web page that plays videos (my bb workarounds are always involve recreating the page as a regular web page). I am guessing that flow player is out of the question. Is there a better way to do this? I want to make as many phones able to use the app as possible so I will be using this kind of format:

```
if: Android OS/iPhone
  - Go to HTML5 Page
else if BB
   if version > 5 
     - Go to HTML5 Page
   else
     - Go to workaround
else if HTC
   - Assuming that html5 will work
else if Opera (for opera Mobi and Mobile)
   - Send to HTML5 page
else
   - Send to workaround
```

**Edit** forgot to add the page [on support for HTML 5](http://letsgomo.com/mobile-web/estimates-of-mobile-phones-and-smartphones-supporting-html5/).

Comment: Why are you breaking out HTC phones? They're all running Android or WP7 these days.

Comment: Well I have had some problems before with HTC phones and JQuery Mobile (which is why I will not use it for this application). I just wanted to see if there would be other kinds of issues as well

Comment: The reason that I take look for their user agent is because I want to make sure as many phones go to the default page as possible, and I know that there is a very easy way to find HTC user agents

Comment: No need - use Android and WP7 user-agents (which are easy to detect).

Comment: @ceejayoz Old HTC phones use Windows Mobile 6.X (.0, .1 or .5) and on those the browser is IE4 based (on .5 is IE5 with things of 6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The majority of phones/devices actually hand-off video playback to the system media player (including the iPhone), most of which are capable of playing some variant of MP4 or H.264. I find using DeviceAtlas http://deviceatlas.com/ or WURFL http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/ to look up the relevant device capabilities (video player, support codecs, etc) and then serve the relevant file/codec(s) and markup (be it an HTML5 video tag, or a simple HREF) to each device is usually the best (and simplest in the end) solution.

FYI - some devices (such as Nokia Symbian devices) support playback of Flash video (FLV/VP6? I believe) within the web page itself (using the Flash plug-in), as do many Android devices (albeit with varying degrees of success).